# AlarmManager reciever doesnt flush alarms (plays after time i spcified)

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Im trying to make an application that keeps my tasks and alarms me on time i specified. I managed to make alarms play independently from each other, but as soon as they go off, they will play every single time i click the checkbox in my custom row adapter. Here's the code:

```
alarmbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmMenagerHelper.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), position , intent,0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            if (alarmbox.isChecked()) {

                Date date = new Date(task.getTaskDate());
                GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                cal.setTime(date);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {if (alarmManager!=null){
                alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
            }                }            }});
```

And also my broadcast reciever :

```
    public class AlarmMenagerHelper extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();
    Toast.makeText(context, "ALARMRRAMRAM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    //Release the lock
    wl.release();
}
```

Im terribly stuck so i decided to come here and ask for little help.

Comment: you are overriding `onClick(View v) of checkbox`, so ofc that will run everytime you click your checkbox. You have to move `AlarmManager` out of it and wake that on specific time you want not on click of checkbox